# Why does socket emit multiple times?

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I'm creating a chat app with sockets. Theres a landing page to enter your nickname and then there's the chat page.

I'm checking to not have multiple nicknames, but what's happening is that when you join after let's say 2 attempts of "nickname already used", the "You joined" message will show 3 times (2 for the failed, and one for the correct).

The "You joined" message is inside the addMessageForm function in chat.js file. This function is called from the name.js file.

Why is that happening?

Here's my code:

server.js

```
const PORT = 3000;
const io = require('socket.io')(PORT);
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

const users = {};

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('new-user', name => {
    if (Object.values(users).includes(name)) {
      socket.emit('name-taken', name);
    }
    if (!Object.values(users).includes(name)) {
      users[socket.id] = name;
      socket.emit('user-accepted');
      socket.broadcast.emit('user-connected', name);
    }
  });
  socket.on('send-chat-message', message => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('chat-message', {
      message: message,
      name: users[socket.id]
    });
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', reason => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', users[socket.id]);
    delete users[socket.id];
  });
});
```

name.js

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const nameContainer = document.createElement('section');
const title = document.createElement('h1');
const form = document.createElement('form');
const nameInput = document.createElement('input');
const submitName = document.createElement('button');

title.innerText = 'Enter Your Name';
submitName.innerText = 'Connect';

const getName = () => {
  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = nameInput.value;
    socket.emit('new-user', name);
    nameInput.value = '';
    socket.on('name-taken', () => {
      feedbackBox('Nickname already taken');
      //const warningBox = document.createElement('section');
      //warningBox.classList.add('name-taken');
      //warningBox.innerText = `'${name}' is already taken. Select another name please.`;
      //container.appendChild(warningBox);
    });
    socket.on('user-accepted', () => {
      title.classList.add('hide');
      nameContainer.classList.add('hide');
      addMessageForm();
    });
  });
};

const appendForm = () => {
  nameInput.classList.add('name_input');
  form.appendChild(nameInput);
  submitName.classList.add('submit_name');
  form.appendChild(submitName);
  nameContainer.appendChild(form);
  nameContainer.classList.add('name_container');
  nameContainer.classList.remove('hide');
  title.classList.remove('hide');
  title.classList.add('name_title');
  container.appendChild(title);
  container.appendChild(nameContainer);
  getName();
};
```

chat.js

```
//const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

const showFeedback = document.createElement('section');
const messageContainer = document.createElement('section');
const messageForm = document.createElement('form');
const messageInput = document.createElement('input');
const submitMessage = document.createElement('button');
const disconnectButton = document.createElement('button');

submitMessage.innerText = 'Send';
disconnectButton.innerText = 'X';

messageContainer.classList.add('message-container');
messageForm.classList.add('send-container');
messageInput.classList.add('message-input');
submitMessage.classList.add('send-button');
disconnectButton.classList.add('disconnect-button');

const addMessageForm = () => {
  showFeedback.classList.add('hide');
  messageContainer.classList.remove('hide');
  messageForm.classList.remove('hide');
  disconnectButton.classList.remove('hide');
  messageForm.appendChild(messageInput);
  messageForm.appendChild(submitMessage);
  container.appendChild(disconnectButton);
  container.appendChild(messageContainer);
  container.appendChild(messageForm);
  appendMessage('You joined');
};
//const name = prompt('What is your name?');
//socket.emit('new-user', name);

socket.on('chat-message', data => {
  appendMessage(`${data.name}: ${data.message}`);
});

socket.on('user-connected', name => {
  appendMessage(`${name} connected`);
});

socket.on('user-disconnected', name => {
  appendMessage(`${name} left the chat`);
});

messageForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const message = messageInput.value;
  appendMessage(`You: ${message}`);
  socket.emit('send-chat-message', message);
  messageInput.value = '';
});

function appendMessage(message) {
  const messageElement = document.createElement('section');
  messageElement.innerText = message;
  messageContainer.append(messageElement);
}

const feedbackBox = message => {
  showFeedback.innerText = message;
  showFeedback.classList.add('feedback-I-disconnect');
  showFeedback.classList.remove('hide');
  container.appendChild(showFeedback);
};

disconnectButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('disconnect-button')) {
    socket.disconnect();
    messageContainer.classList.add('hide');
    messageForm.classList.add('hide');
    disconnectButton.classList.add('hide');
    appendForm();
    feedbackBox('You disconnected from the chat');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like socket.io-client adds duplicates of eventlisteners via `.on()`.

try add `socket.off(event);` before these lines:

```
...
nameInput.value = '';
socket.off('name-taken');        // this line!!!
socket.on('name-taken', () => {
  feedbackBox('Nickname already taken');
  // your commented stuff from above ....
});
socket.off('user-accepted');     // this line!!!
socket.on('user-accepted', () => {
  title.classList.add('hide');
  nameContainer.classList.add('hide');
  addMessageForm();
});
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this made it work!

Could you take a look at this post as well?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59749758/how-to-disconnect-a-client-for-being-inactive-in-chat-for-a-specific-time-socke

Comment: Yes I had some help in there that worked ;) Thanks though!